# How to reload WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an `html` document on my server. I am loading text from this document in my webview. But when I change text in `html` document in my server. My webview is not updating new text. I need to update my webview only when I load my view controller with webview. I am using this code for this but my webview is not updating:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WayViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let url = URL(string: "\(waysURL)") {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(urlRequest)
        }
                
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        webView.reload() 
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I closed the app. Then I updated the text on the server. Went back to the app, my text in the webview didn't update.

Comment: You should tell us more about what you want to achieve. It sounds like what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't need to refresh the webview every second. Only when I go to the controller. The problem is that if I load the webview and exit the app. I will change the text on the server and go back to the app, the text in the webview will not change. The problem is that it does not change after switching to the app.

Comment: @LeoDabus I should use it in `viewWillAppear`? It doesn't work.

Comment: @LeoDabus use `urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` before load view. it is update my webciew info. Is it right?

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok. Thank you! Could you answer the question with a code example? So that I and other users can see the correct example. I just want to make sure I'm using everything right. And there are no errors anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is that you need to reloadFromOrigin to fetch the remote changes. You need also to set your url request cache policy. The default policy is [useProtocolCachePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/useprotocolcachepolicy)

> "If a cached response does not exist for the request, the URL loading system fetches the data from the originating source."

So if the data already exists (that's your scenario) it does NOT fetch from the remote again.

What you need is to ignore the local cached data setting the url request to [reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/reloadignoringlocalcachedata)

> "This policy specifies that no existing cache data should be used to satisfy a URL load request."

---

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WayViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let url = URL(string: "\(waysURL)") {
            let urlRequest: URLRequest = .init(
                url: url,
                cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
            )
            webView.load(urlRequest)
        }    
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        webView.reloadFromOrigin() 
    }
}
```

Comment: what if we only use the webview.reloadFromOrigin() without changing the cachePolicy, should it not force a fresh copy to be obtained from the origin server?
As using reloadFromOrigin() requires revalidation every time, which will make a HEAD request to the originating source to see if the resource has changed and if it is changed, should fetch the data from originating source. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Also, why not use the .reloadRevalidatingCacheData cache policy here instead of .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData?

Comment: @d27saurabh The OP asked to force reload. Feel free to choose the option that's better to your needs.